# Using PHP Class Property Value Outside of the Object

Tags: php, wordpress, class, object, scope

I have a PHP Class that forms the backbone of a WordPress plugin. One of its properties, `post_type_name`, has a value I want to be able to access outside of the object. Namely I need it to construct the string `edit.php?post_type={post_type_name}`.

Is there a way to either read this value directly or to store it as a variable that I can access? It will be used in a separate PHP file that is being included. I do not want to manipulate this value or anything. Just get its contents to avoid having to hard code the string.

So far I have tried using `global`:

```
global $instance;
error_log( print_r( $instance->post_type_name, true ) );
```

as well as

```
global $instance;
$instance = new Class;
```

But all I get in the error log is `PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a method in your class :

```
function getPostTypeName(){
    return $this->post_type_name;
}
```

then get the value by doing :

```
$value = $instance->getPostTypeName();
```

Comment: I tried that code and it results in the page giving an HTTP 500 Error and the error_log stating `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getPostTypeName() on null`

Comment: Scratch that. I figured it out. Had to move my `require_once()` statement calling the options file.